# How do I wrap a Runnable lambda that throws a checked Exception into one that throws a RuntimeException easily

Tags: java, multithreading, lambda

Specifically I have a list of `Runnable` lambdas that do something that can throw a checked `Exception` which in the code below will not work and give a compiler error.

The code below will compile and catch any `RuntimeException` thrown by the lambdas if `doSomething()` methods throw a `RuntimeException` but not a checked `Exception`.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try {
        List<Runnable> runnableList = List.of(
                () -> doSomething(),
                () -> doSomething(),
                // ...
                () -> doSomething()
        );

        runnableList.parallelStream().forEach(metric -> metric.run());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception occured");
    }
}

private static void doSomethingActual () throws Exception {
    someActionThatCanThrowAnException();
}
```

The question I have is how do I easily wrap all the `doSomethingActual()` into some kind of `RuntimeException` with minimal code. In other words I want to write the code below without having to write that for each `doSomething()` method:

```
private static void doSomethingThatWorks() throws RuntimeException {
    try {
        doSomething();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Test exception here");
    }
}
```

In other words I'd like to somehow send the `Runnable` to a wrapper that does this for me. Something along the lines of:

```
private static void doSomethingIdeal(Runnable runnable) throws RuntimeException {
    try {
        runnable.run();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Test exception here");
    }
}
```

But that just seems like wrapper a `Runnable` within a `Runnable`. I suspect there is a better and more elegant solution but I can't quite seem to find it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at Lombok's [SneakyThrows](https://projectlombok.org/features/SneakyThrows).

Answer (score 1):

I asked too soon and found a decent solution. Instead of using `Runnable` I'm going to use `Callable`.

```
try {
    List<Callable> callableList = List.of(
        () -> doSomething(),
        () -> doSomething(),
        // ...
        () -> doSomething());

    callablesList.parallelStream().forEach(callable -> {
        try {
            callable.call();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
        }
    });
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
}
```

This allows me to not have lambdas within lambdas and it allows me to pass the `RuntimeException` to the top level (including the message) and then throw a checked `Exception`.

Of course to note if one callable has an exception it doesn't stop the others because that code is in a parallel stream. If it was just a stream it would stop any further processing.

Answer (score 1):

I've created two projects specific for `IOException` and `SQLException` (because those are the ones I encountered the most). However, I later found https://github.com/pivovarit/throwing-function. With just a single static import you could have done this:

```
List<Runnable> runnableList = List.of(
        unchecked(() -> doSomething()),
        unchecked(() -> doSomething()),
        // ...
        unchecked(() -> doSomething())
);
```

Any exception (including unchecked exceptions) are wrapped in instances of `CheckedException`, so to get those back you'd need to catch this exception and retrieve its cause.